# What kind of Testing I have to use?

Tags: c++, testing, boost

I have written some code that will listen to a web service at all times. Depending upon the outcome I will send some request to the web service, and based on the response I will send further requests. If everything is good I will simply start listening to the web service until some interruption happen.

following the pseudo code(Kind of)

```
class listner
{

string sendReq(Request)
{
   curl_easy_perform();    
  return responseString;
}
connectWebServive()
{
   curl = curl_easy_init();// curl member variable CURL *curl;
    while(true)
    {
       String res = listener(Request1)
       if(res == “some thing”)
       {
           String res = listener(Request2)
       }
       else
       {
           String res = listener(Request3)    
       }
       while(true)
       {
          String res = listener(request4)
          if(somethingWrong)
          {
             break;
          }                  
       }
    }
}
}
```

How can I test this code? Should I use branch coverage or code coverage test?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Branch and line/statement coverage are different metrics to help know what's getting tested or not. In either case, this will depend on the data or event coming as a response from your API, so any interpretation of coverage metrics will mean that you need to create tests for all branches if you expect to perform an accurate analysis.

For readability's sake, I'd recommend not using nested while loops. There should be one listener loop that waits for response. The inner structure of that loop contains your processing logic and if-then-else trees. There should be a default starting request (entry point) and then the logic should check input to decide what the next request will be.

```
current_request = construct_original_request()

while(true) 
{
  response = do_request(current_request) // make a blocking call in thread
  if(response like 'condition A') 
  {
    // do A logic, if any
    current_request = construct_B_request()... // then set up next request
  } else if(response like 'condition B') 
  {
    // do B logic if any
    current_request = construct_C_request()... // then set up next request
  } else 
  {
    current_request = construct_original_request() // back to square one
  }
  wait(1) // let the thread/processor sleep for a non-zero amount of time
}
```